# Unpivoting data fails due to type conflict

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL server 2008 and I am trying to unpivot the data. Here is the data that I am using:

```
TIME_ELAPSE BUILDINGS_CLEARED FLOORS_CLEARED AWAITING_PERC
----------- ----------------- -------------- ------------------
15h 21m     4/4               12/12          0
```

I need output like row values to column:

```
TIME_ELAPSE         15h 21m 
BUILDINGS_CLEARED   4/4
FLOORS_CLEARED      12/12
AWAITING_PERC       0
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT NAME,VALUE
FROM #TEMP_DRILLUP_SUMMARY
UNPIVOT(VALUE FOR NAME IN (Time_Elapse,BUILDINGS_CLEARED,FLOORS_CLEARED,AWAITING_PERC))D
```

The error I received:

> Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 72 The type of column "BUILDINGS_CLEARED" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: Please only tag the SQL Server you are _using_. You tagged 4 different versions which looks unlikely. Also, what have you tried and why did it not work for you?

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to answer by many people

Comment: i have tried union all and got an output but i need it in unpivot query functionality so please correct me the query

Comment: Thanks for clearing up your tags (looks like it is time to upgrade to a [supported version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server)). [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66010733/edit) your question to include your personal attempt. Have you tried anything with the [`unpivot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example) keyword?

Comment: SELECT NAME,VALUE FROM #TEMP_DRILLUP_SUMMARY 
     UNPIVOT(VALUE FOR NAME IN (Time_Elapse,BUILDINGS_CLEARED,FLOORS_CLEARED,AWAITING_PERC))D

Comment: Your query [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d69e24398500f833eb0ebf2a55204363). Looks like your question is still incomplete in order to reproduce your problem. Aim for a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66010733/edit) to add the required details there instead of the comment section.

Comment: No @Sander while running that query i am getting below error

Comment: Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 72
The type of column "BUILDINGS_CLEARED" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: I expected as much. But please... _add all this information to the question_ instead of the comment section! And include the definition of `#TEMP_DRILLUP_SUMMARY` because that is the root of your problem.

Comment: OK @Sander leave it i will check by some other way to find out the issue thank you for your help

Comment: My answer should get you going...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing all columns to the same data type will allow you to use the `UNPIVOT` statement.

**Sample data**

```
create table test2
(
  TIME_ELAPSE nvarchar(10),
  BUILDINGS_CLEARED nvarchar(10),
  FLOORS_CLEARED nvarchar(10),
  AWAITING_PERC int -- different type!
);

insert into test2 (TIME_ELAPSE, BUILDINGS_CLEARED, FLOORS_CLEARED, AWAITING_PERC) values
('15h 21m', '4/4',  '12/12',  '0');
```

**Issue reproduction**

```
SELECT NAME, VALUE
FROM test2
UNPIVOT(VALUE FOR NAME IN (Time_Elapse, BUILDINGS_CLEARED, FLOORS_CLEARED, AWAITING_PERC)) D
```

This gives:

> The type of column "AWAITING_PERC" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

**Solution**

Bring all columns to the same data type before unpivoting (I used `nvarchar(10)` because you did not include your table definition).

```
with cte as
(
  select TIME_ELAPSE,
         BUILDINGS_CLEARED,
         FLOORS_CLEARED,
         convert(nvarchar(10), AWAITING_PERC) as AWAITING_PERC -- align data types
  from test2
)
SELECT NAME, VALUE
FROM cte
UNPIVOT(VALUE FOR NAME IN (TIME_ELAPSE, BUILDINGS_CLEARED, FLOORS_CLEARED, AWAITING_PERC)) D
```

**Result**

```
NAME              VALUE
----------------- -------
TIME_ELAPSE       15h 21m
BUILDINGS_CLEARED 4/4
FLOORS_CLEARED    12/12
AWAITING_PERC     0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ef30013673bdd7313e917686c0b03d17) to see things in action.

Comment: Another method is `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (convert(nvarchar(10), AWAITING_PERC) ) ) v(AWAITING_PERC)` then you don't need the CTE